# awk + add column without adding to header

Tags: bash, awk

I am working on this awk tutorial [here](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/11/awk-examples-insert-remove-update-fields.html).

```
$ head file
Name,Number,Letter
Unix,10,A
Linux,30,B
Solaris,40,C
Fedora,20,D
Ubuntu,50,E
```

this command inserts a new column after the last column. But i do not want to add to the header, how do I do this? I will also, after this, want to add a header name after.

```
$ awk -F, '{$(NF+1)=++i;}1' OFS=, file
Name,Number,Letter,1
Unix,10,A ,2
Linux,30,B ,3
Solaris,40,C ,4
Fedora,20,D ,5
Ubuntu,50,E,6
```

Comment: Your output shows that your input is sloppy w.r.t trailing blanks.

Comment: tks,how do i fix that? Ah i see you mean the space after the Letter column.

Comment: It depends on your choice in editors.  I have various implementations of a program `stb` (strip trailing blanks) which I use to ensure no trailing blanks.  In `vim`, you could use `:g/[ ^I][ ^I]*$/s///` (where the `^I` is a tab) to eliminate trailing blanks and tabs.  At the office, `vim` is set up to display ghastly yellow when there's a trailing blank or tab on a line in a source file.  Etc.  Basically, trailing blanks and tabs are untidy; avoid them when you can.

Comment: That `i` variable is redundant since `NR` provides a count of lines. Setting FS and OFS to the same value in 2 different places is a terrible idea and that's not a reason to set vars in the file list so I'd treat anything else in that tutorial with a lot of suspicion. Use `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} .. ' file` instead of `awk -F, '...' OFS="," file` and get the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: tks ed, found that book [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf) if only I had the time to read all that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip the first line with:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{$(NF+1)=++i;}1' OFS=, file
```

If there can be blanks in the file, then you can use regular expression to mask them out:

```
awk -F, '!/^$/ && NR>1{$(NF+1)=++i;}1' OFS=, file
```

To add a new header, you can do:

```
awk 'NR==1{$0=$0",New_header";} NR>1{$(NF+1)=++i;}1' OFS=, file
```

Like @jaypal said, it could be simply:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{$0=$0",New_header";} NF && NR>1{$(NF+1)=++i;}1' OFS=, file
```

Comment: +1: You can use `NF` to ignore blank lines. `awk -F, 'NF && NR>1{$(NF+1)=++i;}1' OFS=, file`.

Comment: How do I overwrite the existing file, or do i just do a `>` to the same filename?

Comment: @HattrickNZ No, that'll destroy the file! If you have latest awk (4.1 or later) then you can use the `-i` option to do in-pace modification. Otherwise, use a temp file: `awk -F, '{...}' file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file`

Comment: with 4.1 how do i do it? is it  `awk -Fi, ... file`? when in command line it works, but then when I `cat` the file it has not changed

Comment: @HattrickNZ If your awk has `-i` option then : `awk -i -F, '{...}' file` [Read GNU awk manual here.](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $0, (NR>1?NR-1:"new header")}' file
Name,Number,Letter,new header
Unix,10,A,1
Linux,30,B,2
Solaris,40,C,3
Fedora,20,D,4
Ubuntu,50,E,5
```